# Mapping persisted entities using JPA into a instance variable container class of relationship owning class

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, database-design

I have the following database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [user]
(
    [id] BIGINT ,
    [username] VARCHAR(100) ,
    [first_name] VARCHAR(50) ,
    [last_name] VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
);

CREATE TABLE [message]
(
    [id]BIGINT ,
    [Subject] VARCHAR(255),
    [Body] TEXT ,
    [author_id] BIGINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_message_user_author_id(author_id) REFERENCES user(id)
);

CREATE TABLE [message_folder]
(
    [id] BIGINT ,
    [name] VARCHAR(100) (E.g. inbox, sent, drafts etc)
    [system_default] BIT 
    PRIMARY KEY (id),   
);

CREATE TABLE [user_messages]
(
    [id] BIGINT ,
    [user_id] BIGINT ,
    [message_id] BIGINT,
    [message_folder_id] BIGINT,
    [is_read] BIT,
    UNIQUE KEY uk_user_message_user_id_message_id(user_id, message_id),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_user_messages_user_id(user_id) REFERENCES user(id),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_user_messages_message_id(message_id) REFERENCES message(id),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_user_messages_message_folder_id(message_folder_id) REFERENCES message_folder(id)
);
```

I want to be able to map this relationship in my Spring web app where I am using JPA 2.1 with Hibernate provider.

I have the following classes:

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends AuditedEntity {

    public interface RegisterUser extends Default {}

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "username")
    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")
    @UniqueUsername(groups = RegisterUser.class)
    private String username;

    private MessageBox messageBox;
```

Message:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message extends AuditedEntity {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "subject")
    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")
    private String subject;

    @Column(name = "body")
    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")
    private String body;

    @Column(name = "author_id")
    private User author;
```

Message Folder:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message_folder")
public class MessageFolder extends AuditedEntity {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "system_default")
    @NotEmpty
    private boolean systemDefault;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_messages", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "message_folder_id", updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "message_id", updatable = false)})
    private Set<Message> messages = new HashSet<>();
```

The problem I have is that I want to be able to map message folders back to users using a container class called MessageBox.java as below:

```
public class MessageBox {

    private Set<MessageFolder> messageFolders = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<MessageFolder> getMessageFolders() {
        return messageFolders;
    }

    public void setMessageFolders(Set<MessageFolder> messageFolders) {
        this.messageFolders = messageFolders;
    }

    public void addMessageFolder(MessageFolder messageFolder) {
        messageFolders.add(messageFolder);
    }

    public void removeMessageFolder(MessageFolder messageFolder) {
        messageFolders.remove(messageFolder);
    }
}
```

Every user will have an instance of MessageBox.java which will contain MessageFolder instances in a set. These in turn will contain messages.

My question is how do I map this relationship using JPA considering I do not have a [message_box] database table. Any suggestions on how to overcome this, even if it involves a schema redesign would be welcome.

Thank you